# Removing new JTable() from loop

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

I have created a java method which extracts information from a text file, then adds it to a JTable. However, i want to remove the JTable from the loop as it loops a new table three times. I am having an issue doing this.

The code i want to remove out of the loop is displayed is:

```
            JTable table = new JTable(myVector,columnNames) {{
            setOpaque(false);
            setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {{
            setOpaque(true);
            }});
        }};
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table) {{
               setOpaque(false);
               getViewport().setOpaque(false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }

        });
```

This is the full java method:

```
    Vector<Vector<String>> myVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    FileReader fReader = new FileReader("playerscores.txt");
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fReader);
    String input;
    String[] temp;
    while((input=inFile.readLine())!=null) {
        Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
        temp = input.split(",",6);
        for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
            v.add(temp[i]);
            System.out.println(temp[i]+" added");
        }
        System.out.println("V is "+v);
        myVector.add(v);
        System.out.println("End of Line");
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            columnNames.addElement("Player Name:");
        columnNames.addElement("Score:");
        JTable table = new JTable(myVector,columnNames) {{
        setOpaque(false);
        setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {{
        setOpaque(true);
        }});
    }};
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table) {{
           setOpaque(false);
           getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    });

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having? What have you tried?

Comment: @David I Want to add the Jtable into a Panel so i can the Jtable in the middle of the frame. However, when i do this it mutltiples everyone time for every name in the .txt document.

Comment: Seems to me like you can just put the table stuff before the while loop starts?

Comment: Still haven't posted an SSCCE like you where asked to in your last posting, so I'm still not going to waste time guessing what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataModel to store data from file into it. Attach this model to the table